# how to implement https in jboss 7.1.1, i create keystore but getting error untrusted certificate issue on browser

Tags: java

creating keystore and then certificate Add the certificate to the trust store file.
 D:\SSL\CA>keytool -genkey -alias jboss -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore jbosskey.jks
    What is your first and last name?
      [Unknown]:  gaming
    What is the name of your organizational unit?
      [Unknown]:  diipl
    What is the name of your organization?
      [Unknown]:  diiplorg
    What is the name of your City or Locality?
      [Unknown]:  MUM
    What is the name of your State or Province?
      [Unknown]:  MH
    What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
      [Unknown]:  IN
    Is CN=gaming, OU=diipl, O=diiplorg, L=MUM, ST=MH, C=IN correct?
      [no]:  yes

```
D:\SSL\CA>keytool -export -alias jboss -storepass changeit -file server.cer -keystore jbosskey.jks
Certificate stored in file <server.cer>

D:\SSL\CA>keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias jboss -file server.cer -keystore jbosskey.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply and certificate in keystore are identical
java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply and certificate in keystore are identical
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.establishCertChain(KeyTool.java:3338)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.installReply(KeyTool.java:2583)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:998)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```